# Print input dict keys and values in one line

Tags: python

I want to print the all the keys in one line and all the values on the other.

```
a = eval(input())
for keys, values in a.items():
    klist = [keys, values]
    print([keys], "\n", [values])
```

The result is:

```
[123] 
 ['123']
[456] 
 ['456']
[789] 
 ['789']
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
[123, 456, 789]
['123', '456', '789']
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please describe, what kind of input you are inserting?

Comment: a dictionary, like this {123:"123", 456:"456", 789:"789"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `keys()` and `values()` methods of your dict:

```
a = {1: 10, 2: 20}
print(list(a.keys()), list(a.values()), sep='\n')

#[1, 2]
#[10, 20]
```

Note that the `keys()` and `values()` methods return iterators, so you must explicitely build a list from them.